# Query by datetime.now().date of lower from Django DateTimeRangeField

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I use a postgres DateTimeRangeField in Django model. It is the existing database and all the existing rows has both lower range and upper range. Now I need to query for all the rows where date of the lower range is a specific date for example something like rangefield.lower.date==1 .

Please don't tell me to use separate fields for Start date and end date. This system is in production and I need to query that to filter for analytics.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    rangefield = DateTimeRangeField(db_index=True)
    ....
```

I need to query something like `Model.objects.filter(rangefield__lower__date=1)`

Comment: add your `models`

Comment: Added. TIA @AstikAnand

Comment: Try this  "Less than or equal to." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#lte

Comment: Model.objects.filter(rangefield__lte=mydate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `startswith` lookup explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/fields/ranges/#DateTimeRangeField)

```
Model.objects.filter(rangefield__startswith__day=1)
```

If above doesn't work try:

```
Model.objects.filter(rangefield__startswith__date__day=1)
```

Comment: @AswinKumarKP, Thanks for letting me know. Feel privileged to help you out.